# Nginx proxy traffic

Tags: proxy, amazon-s3, nginx

I've got a public S3 bucket with static content and nginx with proxy from my mydomain.com/s3/somefile.txt to s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/somefile.txt. The question is next: does all traffic from S3 go through the nginx when I do a GET request or nginx just redirects it to S3 bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It goes through Nginx. That's how HTTP proxying works.  Some other protocols (e.g SIP) have separate control and data streams that allow you to proxy without touching the data stream, but HTTP does not.